# Data structure to support publish, subscribe and unsubscribe operation using wild card characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am trying to implement a data structure that supports the following operation:

1. publish: a client publishes a message to a topic-name.
2. subscribe: a client subscribes to a topic-name.
3. unsubscribe: a client unsubscribes from a topic-name.

The challenging part here is that the topic-name can be hierarchical, therefore
topic-name looks as below

```
/a/b/f
/a/b/d
/a/c/e
/a/c/f
/a/c/f/t

so I am representing them as a tree which looks as
          '$' --> root  
         /
        a
      /   \ 
     b     c
    / \   / \
   f   d e   f
            /
           t
```

and my python class is as below

```
class TopicTreeNode:
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name
      self.childrens = set()
      self.subscribed_clients = set()
```

I have implemented it by representing the topics in a tree storing the set of clients who have subscribed to the topic.

1. I implemented the publish operation by getting all the clients that
   matches the given topic-name by doing a search in my tree from top to
   bottom.
2. Similarly subscribes involve adding to the tree the
   client(by either creating the topic if it does not exist in the tree)
3. Similarly unsubscribes involve removing the client from the topic node.

Now the challenging part is I have to implement support for wildcard in topic names for publish and subscribe.
so I can have

```
/a/* --> all topics whose parent topic is a [/a/b/f, /a/b/d, /a/c/e, /a/c/f, /a/c/f/t]
/a+/f --> all topics whose parent topic is a followed by any topic followed by topic f [/a/b/f, /a/c/f]
```

can someone suggest how to add wildcard support as well?

Comment: What exactly do `*` and `+` mean here? How would `/a+/f`, `/a*/f`, `/a/+/f` and `/a/*/f` differ? Why in de second example in your question there is `/a/c/f/t` matching when there is no wildcard after `f`?

Comment: + means match any string exactly once.
* means match any string any number of times.
updated the second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse the tree and check if the name of the topic matches with the wildcard with the help of `re` package.

Sample code:

```
import re

nodes = [   '/a/b/f',
            '/a/b/d',
            '/a/c/e',
            '/a/c/f',
            '/a/c/f/t']

for node in nodes:

    if re.fullmatch('/a/.*', node):
        print('{} matched first case'.format(node))

    if re.fullmatch('/a/./f', node):
        print('{} matched second case'.format(node))
```